# Wrong returning value of ajax post data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I receive some dump or additional characters in my response from AJAX.
Here are the code i use.

```
form_data = 'source%5B%5D=email&nature_of_work%5B%5D=plumbing&requestor=asd&location_of_work=asd';
$.ajax({
  url: 'location_of_controller/sample',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {form_data:form_data},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(res){
     console.log(res);
  }
})
```

For the controller
I simply return the data for post.

```
function sample(){
   echo json_encode($this->input->post('form_data'));
}
```

And this are the output.

[image]

Question is why is it that I'm receiving

```
source ]=email&nature;_of_work[]=plumbing&requestor=asd&locati<br>
```

instead of

```
source%5B%5D=email&nature_of_work%5B%5D=plumbing&requestor=asd&location_of_work=asd
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn global_xss_filtering to FALSE in config
open controller/congif.php

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```

But this will turn off the filtering security i guess.